# ERROR: Formula Expression is required on the action attributes

Tags: marketing-cloud, formula

apex class:

```
public class Apexexample {
    public String name{set;get;}
     public String result{set;get;}
    public String show(){
        return name;
    }

}
```

vf page:

```
<apex:page controller="Apexexample" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="inputpage">
            <apex:outputLabel value="enter name"/>
            <apex:inputText value="{! name}" title="name of employee"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="submit" action="{!show}"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
       <apex:pageBlock title="outputll">
               {! result}
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stackexchange! Your post so far provides good context, but you haven't asked a question. This is a question and answer site, and your posts should be phrased as either a question or an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The return type is messing you up, in order to be a valid target of a page action, the return type needs to be either void or PageReference, so change it to void and set the value of the result in the method

Change it to this:

class

```
    public class Apexexample {
        public String name{set;get;}
         public String result{set;get;}
        public void show(){
            result = name;
        }

}
```

Page

```
<apex:page controller="Apexexample" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="inputpage">
            <apex:outputLabel value="enter name"/>
            <apex:inputText value="{! name}" title="name of employee"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="submit" action="{!show}"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
       <apex:pageBlock title="outputll">
               {!result}
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```